# User is not created in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

my issue is when I am creating a user in the rails console then it is not created. You can also check the below code:

**This is my console:**

```rb
Loading development environment (Rails 7.0.4)
irb(main):001:0> User.create(name: 'Tom', photo: 'https://unsplash.com/photos/F_
-0BxGuVvo', bio: 'Teacher from Mexico.')
=> 
#<User:0x00007fb4e899aa80
 id: nil,
 name: "Tom",
 photo: "https://unsplash.com/photos/F_-0BxGuVvo",
 bio: "Teacher from Mexico.",
 posts_counter: nil,
 created_at: nil,
 updated_at: nil>
```

**These are my schema:**

```rb
 create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "text"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "post_id"
    t.bigint "author_id"
    t.index ["author_id"], name: "index_comments_on_author_id"
    t.index ["post_id"], name: "index_comments_on_post_id"
  end

  create_table "likes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "post_id"
    t.bigint "author_id"
    t.index ["author_id"], name: "index_likes_on_author_id"
    t.index ["post_id"], name: "index_likes_on_post_id"
  end

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "text"
    t.integer "comments_counter"
    t.integer "likes_counter"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "author_id"
    t.index ["author_id"], name: "index_posts_on_author_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "photo"
    t.string "bio"
    t.integer "posts_counter"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_foreign_key "comments", "posts"
  add_foreign_key "comments", "users", column: "author_id"
  add_foreign_key "likes", "posts"
  add_foreign_key "likes", "users", column: "author_id"
  add_foreign_key "posts", "users", column: "author_id"
```

**This is my user model:**

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :likes, foreign_key: "author_id"
  has_many :comments, foreign_key: "author_id"
  has_many :posts, foreign_key: "author_id"

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :posts_counter, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }

  def most_recent_posts
    posts.order(created_at: :desc).limit(3)
  end
end
```

Thank you in advance.

You can check the above code and if anyone solves this problem then please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your user model is validating `posts_counter`, but you aren't providing one.

So `User.create` is failing on this validation. You should be able to replicate this output:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 7.0.4)
irb(main):001:0> user = User.create(name: 'Tom', photo: 'https://unsplash.com/photos/F_
-0BxGuVvo', bio: 'Teacher from Mexico.')
=> 
#<User:0x00007fb4e899aa80
 id: nil,
 name: "Tom",
 photo: "https://unsplash.com/photos/F_-0BxGuVvo",
 bio: "Teacher from Mexico.",
 posts_counter: nil,
 created_at: nil,
 updated_at: nil>
> user.errors.messages
# will say something like "posts_counter must be greater than or equal to 0"
```

If you want `posts_counter` to be optional, you must explicitly declare this:

`validates :posts_counter, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }, allow_nil: true`

If you want, you could instead change your migration to set a default value:

```rb
create_table :users do |t|
  ...
  t.integer :posts_counter, default: 0, null: false
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have a validation defined for the `posts_counter` attribute, you should provide a value:

```rb
posts_counter: 0
```

Or you can "relax" your validation to allow blank values:

```rb
validates :posts_counter, 
  numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 },
  allow_blank: true
```

Don't forget you can check the object errors by:

```rb
user = User.create(...)
user.errors.full_messages
```